# Internet access fails after compiling Gitalist

Tags: git, ubuntu, ip, ipconfig

After I downloaded and compiled **Gitalist** on Ubuntu 12.04,
I cannot access to the internet at all.

The compilation process is suspicious in that it took a really long time (>20min.) with massive messages. But it is strange that during compilation, I haven't used any *sudo* command.

I think some files modified in wrong way. I checked IP configuration using GUI tool but it is okay. Do you have any experience in this kind of problem?